# Redirect anonymous ftp login to a certain folder?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, anonymous

How do i set anonymous ftp logins to a certain folder and restrict access if neccessary? (E.g. all anonymous connections are sent to /ftp directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [manual](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html) :

> **`anon_root`**
>   This option represents a directory which vsftpd will try to change into after an anonymous login. Failure is silently ignored